# Register an Inline admin without removing the other packages inlines

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Im trying to add into my adimn an inline box to the User page. 
The problem is that in order to do so, i have to unregister the User admin first:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
```

and register it later with the new inline:

```
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

The problem is that doing so I'm removing all the User admin inlines created by other packages.
Is there a way to "extend" the inlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the original UserAdmin from django.contrib.auth.admin and add the inline to it with `UserAdmin.inlines += [MyInlineAdmin]` - that way you shouldn't need to unregister/reregister at all.